# How can I protect an ini file from being edited?

Tags: python

I have saved the game data to an ini file, how can I protect it from being edited by the user?

Comment: Set the ownership to someone other than the user is a decent start. You'll also need to worry about groups, but it's the same mechanism.

Comment: excuse me,how can i do this?

Comment: If it's on the user's computer you should assume they can do whatever they want. Games like Terraria and Valheim haven't solved it

Comment: There will be always way to edit a local file if users intend to. In case you really want to prevent users to do so, save it online. Another offline solution is to save it in a format that no one other than you knows how to edit (binary file for instance). But it will just slow down skilled users. Instead of worrying that users will cheat by modifying some setting files or so, I suggest putting effort to make a game they don't want to cheat.

Comment: As others commented it is nearly impossible to prevent unwanted editing. Depending on your needs you could use an digital signature to **detect** an editing and siop working of your program/app.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, it's not possible.  You can't do anything to a local file that user is unable to undo.

However, you can obfuscate or encrypt (however simply) that file, so that at least a casual person with a Notepad is likely to give up.  The simplest thing to do is to save data as a pickle file, so that it's easy to manipulate in Python, but looks baffling to a non-techy user/player.

Answer (score 1):

Make somehow a hash / control sum of your ini-file and store at separate file. It will not prevent the ini-file from modification but you'll be able to know if modification occured and react on such user's behaviour.